# How to place Social media icons on right side of navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to line up my social media icons with the navbar, but have them on the right hand side of the display. Could someone help?

The first image is what it looks like now, and the second is what I would like it to look like
[http://imgur.com/a/e0vJQ](https://imgur.com/a/e0vJQ)

Also when it's collapsed it looks like this: [http://imgur.com/AXgjgUH](https://imgur.com/AXgjgUH)
So I'm wondering since I'm trying to change the position of the icons, how it will effect the positioning when collapsed, as I am trying to make everything neat and organized. Could someone tell me the best solution to go about this? I'm struggling with trying to find a solution so if someone could help that would be great

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Example</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link href="css/yourCustom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js" />
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js" />
    </head> 
    <body>
        <nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand" style="color:#000000">Paulo Pinzon-Iradian</a>
                </div>
                <!-- Collection of nav links and other content for toggling -->
                <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li><a href="work.html" style="color:#000000; margin- left:1.5em;">Work</a></li>
                        <li><a href="about.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="contact.html" style="color:#000000; margin-left:1.5em;">Contact</a></li>
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook-square" style="color:#3b5197; margin-left:1.5em;"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-instagram" style="color:#7f5144; margin-left:.8em;"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter-square" style="color:#00c7f4; margin-left:.8em;"></i>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <div />

        <div class="somethingsimple">
            </p>"...I place importance on honesty and expressiveness when creating for a society that is heavily influenced by art."</p>
        </div>

        <footer class="footer">
            <div class="container" style="display: table; height: 50px; overflow: hidden;">
                <p class="text-muted" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">&copy; 2013-2015 Paulo Pinzon-Iradian, All Rights Reserved</p>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

@font-face
{
    font-family:OpenSans-Regular;
    src:url(fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf);
}

.navbar-default{
    background: #fff;
    margin-top:2%;
    border:0px;
}

.navbar-brand
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
}

ul, li, a
{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 22px;
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: 100;
    letter-spacing:-1px;
}

.navbar-toggle
{
    border:0px;
}


.container .jumbotron.no-padding
{
    background: #fff;
    border:0px;
    font-family: font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    color:#000000;
}

.footer {
    position: absolute;
    width:100%;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    text-align:right;
}

.footer .container {
    width: 100%;
}

.right.carousel-control, .left.carousel-control {
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0); /* IE support */
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
}

img
{
    margin:auto;
}

figcaption
{
    display:block;
    text-align:center;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.somethingsimple 
{
  position: absolute;
  width:100%;
  top: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-family: font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 22px;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
}

i
{
float:right;
}

ul.navbar-nav li{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle with some changes since first posting the question:
https://jsfiddle.net/er78k2on/

Thanks for taking the time, have a good day

Comment: `.navbar-nav` floats left, thus your social media icons do not have any more space to the right. Make .navbar-nav NOT float left and you're good to go :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**try apply using these css property to your social icon**

```
  ul.navbar-nav{
float:right;
}

ul.navbar-nav li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

**if still facing problem give a jsfiddle link to your question**

Comment: Okay I applied your changes. But it's not quite. Here is the jsfiddle you asked for https://jsfiddle.net/er78k2on/

Comment: now its working .. check this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/er78k2on/1/
if your problem is solved please mark this answer right.
thanks

Comment: Yes this worked, thank you. Just last question. When the window is minimized and you click the navbar collapse/icon-bar, the menu is on the left while the social media is on the right. Is there a way around this? To either take the social media out of the navbar collapse or have it placed in the left along with the menu? While still keeping the placement of the social media on the full sized window

Comment: you can add media queries like this: @media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
   //your css again and if necessarymark it as !important...
}
or else you can use javascripts to add classes or remove classes